# How do I calculate or estimate how long a battery operated circuit will power an audio exciter?

Tags: power, batteries, audio

I understand that this question has a lot of moving parts to it and I am quite a noob.

I have a battery operated circuit which in turn powers a planar audio exciter (such as this one: https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/Billionsound-Low-Profile-19mm-Sound-Exciter_60350818703.html )

The circuit drives that exciter via a DAC and amplifier, producing a waveform with a set amplitude, duration and spectrum - let's assume for simplicity that it is a continuous, complex "note" of set amplitude - then I'll "dutycycle" it.

Q: How can I estimate how long the battery would last? or alternatively, what would the current draw of the exciter be? How does changing amplitude and frequency change that, and how can I find out from datasheets?

Apologies if it is something really simple to find in a datasheet or extrapolate from it. So far the only solution I can think of, is to empirically measure the current draw of the exciter over a certain amount of time, but there must be a better way.

Comment: There is no way to calculate unless you know how much your amplifier takes current while providing some amplitude level set by some volume control somewhere.

Comment: Measuring the current draw is a very good way, especially if you're lacking the information to calculate it.

Comment: Most speakers have a detailed datasheet. That cheap one does not.